# Java 1.7 is not allowing to access the system root preference in client machine through applet

Tags: applet

We need to get the list of hard printers from client machine through applet call.

It works well in java 1.6. But in 1.7 it throws the exception as below even though we gave all permission.

```
New Method got Error:access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "preferences")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "preferences")
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.prefs.Preferences.systemRoot(Unknown Source)
 at printer.Printers.getAvailableNewPrinters(Printers.java:134)
 at printer.Printers.getAvailablePrinters(Printers.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  Aplication blocked  by security settings
There is a problem with the new version of java 1.7 update 51 onwards as restriction  is done in three levels 
•   Very High: Most secure setting - Only Java applications identified by a non-expired certificate from a trusted authority will be allowed to run.
•   High (minimum recommended): Java applications identified by a certificate from a trusted authority will be allowed to run.
•   Medium - All Java applications will be allowed to run after presenting a security prompt.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc3.html

might help